# how to set navigation bar to the left using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, navigationbar

I am trying to create a navigation bar for my website using bootstrap 5. The problem is I want to make my bar move to the left by using the class margin left auto (ml-auto). I do not know exactly why it did not work for me. Could you help me to figure out the reason, please? Thank you so much!

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Kim Phan</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark"> <!-- make the nav bar size, nav bar font color, navbar background color-->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a> <!--brand color logo-->
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"> 
                <a class="nav-link"href=""> Contact</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item"> 
                <a class="nav-link"href=""> Pricing</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item"> 
                <a class="nav-link"href=""> Download</a>
             </li>
        </ul>
        
    </nav>
</body>
```

[My current navigation bar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0bs7.png)

Comment: I got the expected result by changing ml-auto to ms-auto. Please ignoring my question!

Answer (score 2):

You can no longer set margins with `ml.auto` or `mr.auto` in Bootstrap v5. They are replaced by `ms.auto` and `me.auto`.

"**ms**" and "**me**" stand for "**margin start**" and "**margin end**."

[Auto margins from Bootstrap v5.1 documentation]
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#auto-margins

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"> 
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item"> 
            <a class="nav-link"href="#">Pricing</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item"> 
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Download</a>
         </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

you are using your brand name inside the navbar class that's why the brand name is aligned in the left of navbar.
instead of that you can give your brand name in separete div element. After that your ml-auto attribute will work.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Kim Phan</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
<div>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a> <!--brand color logo-->
</div>
<div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

  <a href="">Conanct</a>
  <a href="#">Pricing</a>
  <a href="#">Download</a>
</div>
        
        
</body>
```